# Ruby - Safely navigated hash when a key could be a string or further hash

Tags: ruby

I'm stuck trying to safely navigate a hash from json.

The json could have a string, eg: 
or it could be further nested:

```
h1 = { location: { formatted: 'Australia', code: 'AU' } }

h2 = { location: 'Australia' }
h2.dig('location', 'formatted')
```

Then String does not have #dig method

Basically I'm trying to load the JSON then populate the rails model with the data available which may be optional. It seems backwards to check every nested step with an if.

Comment: h = { location: 'Australia' };
puts h.dig(:location, :formatted); Gives an error.

Comment: If I run the code there then the error is "String does not have #dig method". Oops, the code is with symbols. h.dig(:location, :formatted)

Comment: Oops, it is my error. Apologies. But still, what do you want it to return if not an error? `nil`? The last value it got to before it couldn't continue? You can do `(h.dig(:location, :formatted) rescue nil)` for the former.

Comment: What output do you expect for `h2.dig(...)`? Should `nil` be returned because the path couldn't fully be traversed? Or do you expect `'Australia'` because that is the first object that can't be digged into?

Comment: It gives an error. I went with the rescue nil statement because it's simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple piece of code like that:

```rb
def nested_value(hash, key)
  return hash if key == ''

  keys = key.split('.')
  value = hash[keys.first] || hash[keys.first.to_sym]
  return value unless value.is_a?(Hash)

  nested_value(value, keys[1..-1].join('.'))
end

h1 = { location: { formatted: 'Australia', code: 'AU' } }
h2 = { 'location' => 'Australia' }

p nested_value(h1, 'location.formatted') # => Australia
p nested_value(h2, 'location.formatted') # => Australia
```

You can also use that method for getting any nested value of a hash by providing key in format `foo.bar.baz.qux`. Also the method doesn't worry whether a hash has string keys or symbol keys.

Comment: Recursion?! Really? For this kind of task plain old good `reduce` is sufficiently enough.

Comment: The idea was in providing some interface that allowed getting nested value without worrying about JSON structure. The author works with some JSON and probably he mets some other similar issues so the method turned out to be like generalized. And recursion is just a loop in the end like `reduce` or something another iteratable

Comment: No recursion is not “just a loop.” It assembles frames on the stack, unlike reducing, and TCO is [off in ruby by default](https://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-tco/). That said, for relatively huge hashes the recursion might blow the execution flow up (unlikely, but still.)

Answer (score 0):

`Hash#dig` has no magic. It reduces the arguments recursively calling `Hash#[]` on what was returned from the previous call.

```rb
h1 = { location: { formatted: 'Australia', code: 'AU' } }
h1.dig :location, :code
#⇒ "AU"
```

It works, because `h1[:location]` had returned *a hash*.

```rb
h2 = { location: 'Australia' }
h2.dig :location, :code
```

It raises, because `h2[:location]` had returned a `String`.

---

That said, the solution would be to reimplement `Hash#dig`, as usually :)

Explicitly taking into account that it’s extremely trivial. Just take a list of keys to *dig* and (surprise) `reduce`, returning either the value, or `nil`.

```rb
%i|location code|.reduce(h2) do |acc, e|
  acc.is_a?(Hash) ? acc[e] : nil
end
#⇒ nil

%i|location code|.reduce(h1) do |acc, e|
  acc.is_a?(Hash) ? acc[e] : nil
end
#⇒ "AU"
```

---

Shameless plug. You might find the gem [`iteraptor`](https://github.com/am-kantox/iteraptor) I had created for this exact purpose useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this lead to the expected behaviour (see examples below) but you can define a patch for the Hash class as follow:

```
module MyHashPatch

  def safe_dig(params) # ok, call as you like..
    tmp = self
    res = nil
    params.each do |param|
      if (tmp.is_a? Hash) && (tmp.has_key? param)
        tmp = tmp[param]
        res = tmp
      else
        break
      end
    end
    res
  end

end

Hash.include MyHashPatch
```

Then test on your hashes:

```
h1 = { location: { formatted: 'Australia', code: 'AU' } }
h2 = { location: 'Australia' }

h1.safe_dig([:location, :formatted]) #=> "Australia"
h2.safe_dig([:location, :formatted]) #=> "Australia"

h1.safe_dig([:location, :code]) #=> "AU"
h2.safe_dig([:location, :code]) #=> "Australia"
```